# C vfprintf function not working with string arguments

Tags: c, string, printing

I'm trying to use vfprintf in the following way
vfprintf(fp, buffer, arg);
fp log file that I create using the date and time of the run, a buffer and the rest of the args

```
fp = fopen(filename, "a");
va_start(arg, message);
vprintf(message, arg); // print stdout
vfprintf(fp, buffer, arg); // print to file
va_end(arg);
fclose(fp);
```

it works perfectly with numbers and it dies horribly with the error: vfprintf source not found at ....

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using a 64-bit architecture where variable length `arg` can only be passed over once. To make more passes copy `arg` using `va_copy()`:

```
va_list arg, arg2;
va_start(arg, message);
va_copy(arg2, arg);
vprintf(message, arg); // print stdout
va_end(arg);
vfprintf(fp, buffer, arg2); // print to file
va_end(arg2);
```

From `man va_arg`:

> The va_arg() macro expands to an expression that has the type and value
>          of  the  next  argument in the call.  The argument ap is the va_list ap
>          initialized by va_start().  **Each call to va_arg() modifies ap  so  that
>          the  next  call returns the next argument.**  The argument type is a type
>          name specified so that the type of a pointer to an object that has  the
>          specified type can be obtained simply by adding a * to type.
>
> ...
>
> **If  ap is passed to a function that uses va_arg(ap,type) then the value
>          of ap is undefined after the return of that function.**

Comment: Hi, thank you! It seems to be working. How do you explain the fact that if you put a number instead of string it works though? It should have to return the number twice as well, shouldn't it?